# How to access the innerHTML of multiple Quill instances with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I am trying to have multiple Quill text editor instances on a single page, I achieved that but now I am straggling on how to get the innerHTML of each. To create a single instance and get its innerHTML and assign it to a hidden input, I use the following:

```
// CREATE A QUILL INSTANCE

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
    toolbar: [
        [{'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],
        [{'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],
        [{'font': [] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        ['link', 'blockquote', 'code-block', 'image', 'video'],
    ]
},
placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
theme: 'snow'
});

// GET THE innerHTML OF THE QUILL INSTANCE ANS ASSIGN IT TO A HIDDEN FIELD.

var form = document.getElementById("writeArticleForm");
form.onsubmit = function() {
    // Populate hidden form on submit
    var articlebody = document.querySelector('input[name=articleBody]');
    var html = document.querySelector(".ql-editor").innerHTML;
    articlebody.value = html;
    return true;
}
```

But when I create for instance, two instances of QUILL, how could I use the  querySelector to get the innerHTML of each instance and assign it to a variable?

Comment: You'd want to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop through those results (might need a little [know-how](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) to iterate correctly)

Comment: @GammaGames, thank you for your reply, I have visited the aforementioned website and a couple of others, but honestly, I couldn't figure out how to get assign each variable the correct value (innerHTML). I am not very familiar with JavaScript. But I'll keep searching. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll get a little answer goin for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements that match a class name. To iterate over the resulting [`NoteList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you'll have to convert it to an array, my method of choice is using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
document.querySelector("#read_button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let output = document.querySelector("#output");
  let form = document.querySelector("#form");
  output.innerHTML = "";
  form.innerHTML = "";
  // Get all inputs
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
  // Spread NodeList into array and iterate
  [...elements].forEach((input, index) => {
    output.innerHTML += `<li>${input.innerHTML}</li>`;
    form.innerHTML += `<input type="hidden" id="input${index}_value" value="${input.innerHTML}">`;
  });
});
```

```css
.input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
#read_button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="input">Input 1</textarea>
<textarea class="input">Input 2</textarea>
<textarea class="input">Input 3</textarea>
<textarea class="input">Input 4</textarea>
<button id="read_button">
  Read Inputs
</button>
<p>Output:</p>
<ul id="output"></ul>

<form id="form"></form>
```

Comment: Thank you, really for the time and effort. Pardon me, but only one question, how may I pass each value to a hidden field? E.g: hidden_input1: input1_value, hidden_input2: input2_value? very much really appreciated.

Comment: I'll edit the question to put it in the list and also set it to a hidden input

Comment: @MurphyAdam I updated the snippet to add hidden inputs, it gets the id based on to the index in the loop

Comment: I had implmented only a single instance per page. But now I'd go and test your answer. Really thank you for your time and effort.